# Digital signatures and encryption in GMail

Tags: ssl, g-suite, gmail, pgp, digital-signatures

I just wonder if there is a way to use SSL certificates or PGP keys for signing my email.

At the moment I have to setup S/MIME in Outlook (or another thick client) to send signed messages via SMTP. It works for me, but I'm looking for a way to do the same using GMail's web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FireGPG](http://getfiregpg.org/) can use GnuPG, but I couldn't find any mention of S/MIME.

Answer (score 2):

[Gmail S/MIME](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/592) plugin for firefox.